# Fail Flink Job if source/sink/operator has undefined uid or name

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In my jobs I'd like every source/sink/operator should to have `uid` and `name` property defined for easier identification.

```
operator.process(myFunction).uid(MY_FUNCTION).name(MY_FUNCTION);
```

Right now I need to manually review every job to detect missing settings. How can I tell Flink to fail job if any `name` or `uid` is not defined?

Answer (score 2):

Once you get a `StreamExecutionEnvironment` you can get the graph of the operators.

When you don't define a name Flink autogenerates one for you. In addition if you set a name, in case at least of sources or sinks, Flink adds a prefix `Source:` or `Sink:` to the name.

When you don't define a uid, the uid value in the graph at this stage is null.

Given your scenario, where the name and uid are always the same, to check all operator have been provided with the name and uid you can do the following:

```
        getExecutionEnvironment().getStreamGraph().getStreamNodes().stream()
            .filter(streamNode -> streamNode.getTransformationUID() == null ||
                    !streamNode.getOperatorName().contains(streamNode.getTransformationUID()))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This snippet will print all the operator that doesn't match with your rules.

This won't work in the 100% of cases, like using a uid which is a substring of the name. But you have here a general way to access to the operators information and apply the filters that fits in your case and perform your own strategy.

This snippet can de used as part of your CI or use it directly in your application.